# Beautiful Soup Scraping

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having issues with old working code not functioning correctly anymore.

My python code is scraping a website using beautiful soup and extracting event data (date, event, link).

My code is pulling all of the events which are located in the `tbody`. Each event is stored in a `<tr class="Box">`. The issue is that my scraper seems to be stopping after this `<tr style ="box-shadow: none;>` After it reaches this section (which is a section containing 3 advertisements on the site for events that I don't want to scrape) the code stops pulling event data from within the `<tr class="Box">`. Is there a way to skip this tr style/ignore future cases?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='bs4')

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://10times.com/losangeles-us/technology/conferences').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
   #---Get Event Data---
    test1=[]
    table = soup.find('tbody')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr') #find table rows (tr)
    for x in table_rows:   
        data = x.find_all('td')  #find table data
        row = [x.text for x in data]
        if len(row) > 2: #Exlcudes rows with only event name/link, but no data.
            test1.append(row)
test1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, so you don't see more results. You can use this example to load more pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://10times.com/ajax?for=scroll&path=/losangeles-us/technology/conferences"
params = {"page": 1, "ajax": 1}
headers = {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

for params["page"] in range(1, 4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    print("Page {}..".format(params["page"]))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).content,
        "html.parser",
    )
    for tr in soup.select('tr[class="box"]'):
        tds = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for td in tr.select("td")]
        print(tds)
```

Prints:

```
Page 1..
['Tue, 29 Sep - Thu, 01 Oct 2020', 'Lens Los Angeles', 'Intercontinental Los Angeles Downtown, Los Angeles', 'LENS brings together the entire Degreed community - our clients, invited prospective clients, thought leaders, partners, employees, executives, and industry experts for two days of discussion, workshops,...', 'Business Services IT & Technology', 'Interested']
['Wed, 30 Sep - Sat, 03 Oct 2020', 'FinCon', 'Long Beach Convention & Entertainment Center, Long Beach 20.1 Miles from Los Angeles', 'FinCon will be helping financial influencers and brands create better content, reach their audience, and make more money. Collaborate with other influencers who share your passion for making personal finance...', 'Banking & Finance IT & Technology', 'Interested 7 following']
['Mon, 05  - Wed, 07 Oct 2020', 'NetDiligence Cyber Risk Summit', 'Loews Santa Monica Beach Hotel, Santa Monica 14.6 Miles from Los Angeles', 'NetDiligence Cyber Risk Summit will conference are attended by hundreds of cyber risk insurance, legal/regulatory and security/privacy technology leaders from all over the world. Connect with leaders in...', 'IT & Technology', 'Interested']

... etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for the above answer. I wasn't aware of this, however, you're solution makes sense to me!